# Agregating by field value on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection composed of documents similar to one below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc916a72440b14b3f0ec096"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-11-11T11:07:03.968+03:00"),
    "actions" : [
        {
            "type" : "Type1",
            "action" : true
        },
        {
            "type" : "Type2",
            "action" : true
        },
        {
            "type" : "Type3",
            "action" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to count all the action types based on the boolean value of the actions.action property.

This is how I came so far:

```
db.Actions.aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: { $year: "$date" },
                month: { $month: "$date" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
);
```

As you can see this only gives me the count of the documents in the collection grouped by the action date.

What I need is something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2019,
        "month" : 10,
        "day" : 13
    },
    "Type1": 300,
    "Type2": 200,
    "Type3": 120,
    "count" : 305
}
```

Is this possible with a query or should I go in the direction of creating a cursor and agregating the values with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Actions.aggregate([
  // Unwind to de-normalize the array
  { "$unwind": "$actions" },
  // Group on both day and "type"
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "date": {
        "$toDate": {
          "$subtract": [
            { "$toLong": "$date" },
            { "$mod": [{ "$toLong": { "$toDate": "$date" } }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ] }
          ]
        }
      },
      "type": "$actions.type"
    },
    "total": { "$sum": { "$toLong": "$actions.action" } }
  }},
  // Roll-up the grouping to just by "day"
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.date",
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.type", "v": "$total" } }
  }},
  // Convert to key/value output
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        { "_id": "$_id", "count": { "$sum": "$data.v" } },
        { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

To summarize:

The [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is needed simply because you want to "group" on a value which is inside an array of a document. Using this "de-normalizes", or essentially makes each array element into a new document for the same property and all other "parent" properties of the document in which that array resides. In simple speak, you get a "copy" of the containing document for every array member as a new document.

The next [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) basically uses a "Date math" approach to *rounding* to a singular day. This is a bit prettier than methods like [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) and [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) etc, and actually returns a `Date` object, which you client language of choice will understand.

Of course this is a *compound grouping key*, meaning that the other part is of course the `type` field from the array of `actions`. And since you only want `true` results to count, we apply [`$toLong`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) again in order to translate the `Boolean` into a numeric value to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) ( which basically means "count" when it's `0` or `1` ). In older releases you could also do this using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), but the simple *type conversion* is a lot more simple to read for intent.

The rest of this is basically about translating to the *expected* "key/value"* output of the question. Really, you got the desired result in the very first [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operation but to be "key/value"  you need to put all those results into an array ( by "date" of course ) using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/), and then convert that array into the root document using the [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) function.